# GeoCoordinate - How do I format it into for latitude, longitude?

Tags: android, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I'm using the `PositioningManager` class to get my current geocoordinates

```
PositioningManager posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
GeoPosition position = posManager.getPosition();
Log.d(TAG, "onMyLocationClick: " + position.getLatitudeAccuracy() + ", " + position.getLongitudeAccuracy());
```

however it's returning me

`1.07374182E9, 1.07374182E9`

for lat lng

how do I format it so that it's like:

`40.712776, -74.005974`

Check permissions code:

```
public void checkLocationPermission(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        PositioningManager posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                        posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
                        GeoPosition position = posManager.getPosition();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionGranted: " + position.isValid());

                        try {
                            String strLatitude = Location.convert(position.getCoordinate().getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
                            String strLongitude = Location.convert(position.getCoordinate().getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onMyLocationClick: " + strLatitude + ", " + strLongitude);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onPermissionGranted: Error: " + e);
                        }

                    }
                    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionDenied: Permission denied");
                    }
                    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown: Called");
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear, Position Manager as in Here Maps?

Comment: @trinadhthatakula yes it's for HereMaps, I thought it was an Android feature, my bad

Comment: in GeoPosition Object there will be a boolean value (VALID) is it false???

Comment: if it is false then it means location details are not valid you might not have  requested location permission from the user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format GPS latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382230/how-to-format-gps-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: did you request location permission first??

Comment: Yes I did, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: also, check `position.isValid()` to know if the acquired location value is Valid

Comment: the ```isValid()``` says its false, ive added the full code above. The callback method is returning permission granted. Still not getting degress https://i.imgur.com/xgZouxN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Android's [android.location.Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) for processing a HERE SDK `GeoPosition` class.

Just follow the [HERE SDK sample app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/positioning/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/basicpositioningsolution/BasicPositioningActivity.java)

specifically [line 344](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/374767bdf8d6717652255f51e33ba50132b519a4/positioning/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/basicpositioningsolution/BasicPositioningActivity.java#L344)

```
GeoPosition geoPosition
...
final GeoCoordinate coord = geoPosition.getCoordinate();
sb.append("Type: ").append(String.format(Locale.US, "%s\n", locationMethod.name()));
sb.append("Coordinate:").append(String.format(Locale.US, "%.6f, %.6f\n", coord.getLatitude(), coord.getLongitude()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is not the position. Use `getCoordinate().getLongitude()` and so on.

Comment: i've tried that ```position.getCoordinate().getLatitude()```, but it returns ```-1.7976931348623157E308, -1.7976931348623157E308```  https://i.imgur.com/Ox5ChHK.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK` rather than `LocationMethod.GPS`.

And then use `getCoordinate().getLongitude()`.